# How to use the Startboostrap "Agency" theme?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, gulp, less

Let me preface this with a disclaimer. I'm a pretty new to web design and have been pushing myself outside of just relying on using Wordpress and purchasing Wordpress themes for my website needs. So please excuse my utter ignorance and potential lack of understanding :)

Anyway here's my question/situation...

I am working a redesigning one of the websites I have that is currently on Wordpress. I'm taking the Bootstrap route and downloaded the "Agency" theme from Startbootstrap (https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/agency/)

I like the overall theme and just need to make some aesthetic changes to match my branding and style better. I downloaded all of the source files and am editing them using the Atom text editor. I also have installed node.js and gulp. Gulp is installed globally and locally in the Agency source folder.

Now here's the part where I feel like a total dweeb for not being able to figure out. I've been able to change the text adn images just fine. Where I'm having issues is that I can't for the life of me figure out how to change colors, text size etc... in the css files.

The css files that are included are agency.css and agency.min.css
There is also a "less" files folder which includes agency.less, mixins.less and variables.less

To give you an example of one thing I've like to do is to change the color of the navigation button background. In the original theme the background is yellow. I'd like to make the background green. How on earth do I do that?

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!I'm sure I've left out some details that are needed to better help me, so please let me know what I need to provide to help you help me.

Comment: less is a language that enables some nice features that css doesn't have natively (like variables, nesting codes, ...). More info here http://lesscss.org/ . The downside is: it needs to be compiled, to do that you can use the less client or a a tool like grunt + less plugin. I think looking at the grunt and the less websites should help you to better understand the whole concept and you will be able to ask more detailed questions.

Comment: This seems to be a very broad question, don't you think It would require a lot of effort and guidance for explanations.

Comment: have you had a look at https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-agency/issues/71?